# Symfony DomCrawler take all div element in html file

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

I want to take all  element in html file.

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
for($i = 0; $i < $crawler->filter("div")->count(); $i++){
     $div = $crawler->filter("div")->html();
```

Doing this I always take the first div element:
How can I take all div element and add in an array?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to achieve your goal:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$div = $crawler->filter('div')->each(function($node) {
    return $node->html();
});

// Array of result = $div 
// Number of result = sizeof($div)
```

Comment: Okay, it works, but it exclude the <div> tag. I need that it return <div ec...>

Comment: I don't see anything ;)

Comment: <div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" class="left w450 m20"><span class="citta">Milano</span></div>

Comment: No, i only have to try information from this with regex and I want to divide all <div> that i have using crawler.

Comment: so use only: `$data = $crawler->html();`

Comment: But how I can loop on every div?

Comment: It's like this : 
<html>
<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" class="left w450 m20"><span class="citta">Milano</span></div> 
<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" class="left w450 m20"><span class="citta">Milano</span></div> 
<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" class="left w450 m20"><span class="citta">Milano</span></div> 
<div data-provincia="mi" data-nazione="it" class="left w450 m20"><span class="citta">Milano</span></div>
</html>

Comment: Okay. Try with the initial solution I posted and change this: `$div = $crawler->filter('html')->each(function($node) { return $node->html(); });`

Comment: It's all in the first key of the array